# Вызов сервиса с помощью Postman

Tags: api, postman

Задача следующая:
Нужно вызвать сервис для получения информации о пользователе.
Есть следующие данные.

```
    POST:https://api.mindbox.ru/v3/operations/sync?endpointId=hiring&operation=get.user
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Accept: application/json
    Authorization: Mindbox secretKey="QQ5oyl5DLBhKeLrQO1A2"
{
  "customer": {
  "email": "demo@mindbox.cloud"
    }
}
```

Я сначала использую метод Post и получаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я не очень понимаю что делать дальше и как мне получить нужные данные.

Comment: Ну вам сервис ответил NotFound, т.е. видимо пользователя с таким email не существует. Что делать - ну попробуйте другой email.

Comment: @insolor Может быть я что то не так делаю и он не может его найти?

Comment: Без понятия. Смотрите документацию по сервису, обращайтесь в техподдержку.